# BootstrapVue - use tooltips on select options?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using BootstrapVue, and I have a `<b-form-select>` in which I want to display a tooltip for each `<b-form-select-option>`. I have the following:

```
 <b-form-select-option v-for="opt in options" :key="opt.value" :value="opt.value" :title="opt.text" v-b-tooltip.hover>{{opt.name}}</b-form-select-option>
```

The tooltip does not display, only the regular title. Now I know that "Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning", as the docs say, but I don't know whether this is automatically added or not if I import the BootstrapVue plugin (`import './plugins/bootstrap-vue'`) or whether it needs to be explicitly included somehow, in which case, how? The docs are not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's already included (in the UMD bundle).
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/#dependencies

The fastest way would be to try it out and see if this works or check your `yarn.lock`/`package-lock.json` (search and see if it's included as a dependency of bootstrap vue).
Or you could use any webpack bundle analyzer (backed-in if you're using Nuxt.js).

This one also confirms it: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3681

I just `yarn add bootstrap-vue`'ed and this is the result. So yeah, it is already included out of the box.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you're right, package-lock.json reveals its presence. So there must be some other reason why the tooltips are not displaying. I need to investigate further.

Comment: Check your console or try to debug it with vue devtools maybe (inspecting some components can be very helpful to understand how they work) and post a new question ! :D Feel free to accept the answer if it helped. :)